# Expand/collapse a row in ag grid community version using angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

Please help me to write a code in angular to expand/ collapse a row using ag-grid community version not the enterprise version

Tried by cell rendering but it’s not working and api method ,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-community';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    gridOptions: AgGridOptions;
    gridApi: AgGridApi;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.gridOptions = {
            rowExpandable: true,
            suppressRowExpandColumn: true,
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    headerName: 'Name',
                    width: 100
                },
                {
                    headerName: 'Expand',
                    width: 20,
                    cellRenderer: 'rowExpandButtonRenderer'
                }
            ]
        };

        this.gridApi = this.grid.getApi();
    }

    function rowExpandButtonRenderer(params) {
        const { rowNode, column } = params;
        const isExpanded = rowNode.expanded;
        return (
            <button
                type="button"
                className={`ag-row-expand-button ${isExpanded ? 'ag-row-expand-button-collapsed' : ''}`}
                rowNodeId={rowNode.id}
            >
                {isExpanded ? '-' : '+'}
            </button>
        );
    }

    // Expand the row with the ID 1
    async expandRow() {
        await this.gridApi.setRowNodeExpanded(1, true);
    }

}
```